# XMLHttpRequest tag

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = receiveResponse;
xhr.send();
```

Does the "true" parameter imply that the object loads asynchronously?
If this is not the case, what does the "true" do specifically?

Comment: This is trivial to answer by [reading the manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) or by [reading the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29).

Comment: Look it up yourself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29).  And the default is true.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the `true` value means that the request is asynchronous.  Here is a link to the W3Schools page on this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Here is the W3 link: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method

Comment: That is not the W3C page. That is the W3Schools page. They are not a reliable resource.

Comment: @Quentin You are correct, I have altered the post.

Comment: @Quentin I have also added the W3C link.

Comment: Quentin, not only were your links not as helpful as either of the links Kyle posted, but you stuck around to comment negatively on a a helpful comment on a question which you well knew the answer beforehand, but refused acutely to answer. Thank you Kyle.

Comment: @user1821973 Thank you.  I hope that I was able to answer your question.  As stated by another user, `true` is the default value.

Comment: @user1821973 — Since two of those links were *the same link*, that is nonsense.

Comment: @Kyle — W3Schools is W3Schools, not the W3C and not the W3C Schools. W3Schools has nothing to do with the W3C except for two characters in their name, which they trade off for a huge pile of undeserved reflected glory.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method

Comment: @Quentin I understand that.  As I mentioned in my first 2 responses to you, I have corrected the links, and have posted the actual W3 link.

Comment: @Kyle — Your correction attributes the W3Schools content to "the W3C schools".

Comment: @Kyle — You still haven't removed the C from W3CSchools, but you have removed it from W3C (where it belongs)